# How to achieve this scrolling effect in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How do I achieve this scrolling effect in Boostrap? Have a fixed image background with the content div overlayed on top when scrolling:

http://www.standardhotels.com/culture/things-to-do-july-2017-new-york-los-angeles-miami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could achieve this. You could fix a background image to `html` and offset the body, adding padding to keep text in the viewport. For example:

```
html {
  background: url(DESIRED BACKGROUND IMAGE) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  background:lightblue;
  padding-left:150px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position:relative;
  left:-150px;
  top:80%;
}
```

[Check out this basic (but very cute) kitten example](https://jsfiddle.net/1vfjaz95/).

### EDIT

Looking further into your example's code, you could also add `margin-top` to the body and remove the positioning `top`. Your example shows `margin-top: calc(100vh - 140px) !important;`

[Here's an updated version of my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vfjaz95/1/) with the properties swapped. You can see that the effect is very similar.

Comment: Thanks! So could put this within a main container div and have it work with a sticky header navigation and have footer at the bottom?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for Parallax scrolling. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) is the link with working demo on how to achieve this.

Comment: He's not looking for parallax scrolling. He's looking for a fixed background image with offset content.

Comment: @jswebb well from his question [this demo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm) looks pretty much the same. And it has a fixed background as well